# Multiple saas apps on appstore from one developers account, possible?

Tags: ios, reactjs, app-store, saas

i have a simple query. I am planning on making a saas product. 3 apps(customer, admin, employee) for different clients. Each client will have different branding, different billing accounts and different firebase project.

From what I have heard apple will mark these apps as spam. I cant upload more than one from one developers account. These are custom personalised apps so i dont want to nor can I make them bundle into one single app.

Whats the solution to the apples spam rule? Should I make a different developers account for each client and upload the apps? Or is it possible to have a single developers account and upload all the apps from that account?

Any help is appreciated. I just need guidance.

I am in the planning/research phase so I have not tried anything.

Comment: Who is the "audience" for these apps?  Your customers employees or your customers customers?  For the first case you could look at custom app distribution. Your customers would need to use Apple Business Manager to access the custom app you publish to them. For the second case each of your customers should set up their own Apple Developer membership and you can publish the relevant apps through their membership

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. So the audience is my customer's customers. E.g doctors apps. The doctor is my client. The admin app is for the doctor, tbe customer app is for the doctors clients, so that they can book etc. The employee app is for the doc's assistant/helpers etc.

Comment: I would seriously consider whether there are any benefits of multiple mobile apps vs a mobile responsive web site.  Certainly it seems that the doctor app and the employee app would be better off as web apps; They are almost certainly going to have a desktop/laptop.  Then consider whether the patient wants to download and install an app vs simply using a web site via their phone